# What is the difference between Brigo and Mercurio's book and Andersen and Piterbarg's book?

Tags: interest-rates, books

I'm referring to **Interest Rate Models** by Brigo and Mercurio and **Interest Rate Modelling Volume 1-3** by Andersen and Piterbarg.

Both are around 1000 pages, and are frequently recommended as "bibles" for interest rate models.

But what's the difference between the two? Pros and cons, etc?

Answer (score 6):

I've delved deeply into both texts and engaged in extensive discussions with peers in the industry. Here's my perspective:

Brigo and Mercurio prove to be more beneficial. Upon mastering their content, one finds themselves well-prepared for a quantitative position interview. The clarity of their explanations is exceptional, ensuring that after each study session, there's always a valuable takeaway. This clarity also facilitates easier recollection of previously covered material as you advance through the book.

Conversely, Andersen and Piterbarg adopt a more technical approach. I frequently found myself lost amidst the mathematical subtleties, spending more time grappling with the technical aspects than applying the learned techniques.

In summary, Brigo and Mercurio excel in teaching practical techniques, whereas Andersen and Piterbarg focus more on the mathematical foundations. Those with a PhD in Mathematics (or a related field) might find Andersen and Piterbarg less challenging, but even then, it's debatable whether it offers the same holistic understanding of connecting concepts as Brigo and Mercurio does.

A particular point of frustration with Andersen and Piterbarg is the delayed introduction to interest rate modeling. The initial sections are dedicated to finite difference methods and Monte Carlo simulations, whereas Brigo and Mercurio dive straight into the heart of interest rate modeling.

Comment: A&P is newer. Is there any benefit to that?

Comment: Not really. It is updated more frequently (mostly due to frequent corrections of the typos) but the core content does not change. In fact, Brigo and Mercurio is a bit more up to date in terms of topics, even though the latest version is older.